# Where is storaged the publickey for any account?

Tags: accounts, signature

I have been reading the Ethereum Yellow paperthat for any account there are four parameters:

- nonce
- balance
- storageRoot
- codeHash

A transaction is signed using three parameters: r,s,v

According to the ECDSA paper of The Elliptic Curve Digital Signature Algorithm (ECDSA)(https://web.archive.org/web/20170921160141/http://cs.ucsb.edu/~koc/ccs130h/notes/ecdsa-cert.pdf) for a sign verification [image: Extract from the paper]

- Domain parameters:
        - p,q curve generator
        - g generator of the finite field
- Public key: y
- Signature: r,s
- Message: m

I know that v is used for checking the parity and finitness of the point r[Appendix F from yellow paper), but for ECRECOVER I think that at least, g needs to be provided.

I can't find any information about this.

If you have some documentation about this, please let me know!

Comment: Once the computation is complete, the public key is no longer needed. The account's address is extracted from the 40 least significant bytes of the public key (more precisely, the hash of the public key), and the public key is "thrown away".

Answer (score 1):

Solved, Ethereum allways uses the same curve secp256k1.

Thank you all